# Angular 2 how to update the template only when model value fulfills the condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to update a view only when the number of total votes is multiplication of ten. I'm incrementing a random element of an array `rows` each 10 milliseconds, they sum up to the total number of votes. Is there an easy way in angular 2 to bind and display model value in a template only when a certain condition is fulfilled?

Template:

```
<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item" *ngFor="let row of rows">{{ row }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h3 class="title">Total number of votes: {{ votes }}</h3>
```

Comment: {{parseInt(votes/10)*10}}

Comment: I'd like also not to update rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question. You can have two variables (rows and rowsDisplays)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
  <div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item" *ngFor="let row of rowsDisplay">{{ row }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  rowsDisplay:any[]=[];
  rows:any[]=[];

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.rows.push(new Date());
      if (this.rows.length%10==0) //or another condition
        this.rowsDisplay=[].concat(this.rows); //you can't do this.rowsDisplay=this.rows, 
                            //because then this.rowsDisplay will be this.rows

    },1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Sorry for not being clear while asking a question. I didn't want to share my component, because I wanted to see some other, cleaner options than having two states. One for rowDisplay and one for rows. But that's very similar how my component looks like. The difference is that i forgot `==0` I was not aware that 5%3 evaluates to true in javascript. Also awesome idea with creating a copy of an array by using `[].concat()`, but I discovered that while passing a reference it work as well just fine. So `this.rowsDisplay=this.rows;` is ok. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Be careful if you equals rowsDisplay to rows. e.g. If in my code you make this.rowsDisplay=this.rows, after 10 seconds, 10 lines are showing, then, each second a new "li" are show (empty, but you can see the "marker" of the li), after 10 seconds more show the 20 lines fully.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, clean and "Angular", you should use a basic [Pipe](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe).

Your pipe would look like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'ten'})
export class MultiplesOfTenPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): number {
    return Math.floor(value / 10) * 10;
  }
}
```

This will only update the value of `votes` in the template / view when it is a number divisible by 10.

Check out this link to see it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzuqnn